# How can i inject a class that needs context into Broadcast Receiver with hilt?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

So i have a class that i would like to inject into BroadcastReceiver.

Here is the class:

```
class SomeClass @Inject contructor(@ActivityContext private val ctx: Context){
    fun doStuff(){...}
}
```

When i tried this i get this error: `error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] @dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ActivityContext android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.`

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class Broadcast: BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Inject lateinit var someClass: SomeClass

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
          someClass.doStuff()
    }
}
```

I assume is a problem with the context of `SomeClass` because i tried it removing that parameter and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this class:

```
/**
 * This class is created in order to be able to @Inject variables into Broadcast Receiver.
 * Simply Inherit this class into whatever BroadcastReceiver you need and freely use Dagger-Hilt after.
 */

abstract class HiltBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    @CallSuper
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
    }
}
```

Then, your `BroadcastReceiver` should look like this:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class BootReceiver : HiltBroadcastReceiver() {

    // Injection -> Example from my application
    @Inject
    lateinit var internetDaysLeftAlarm: InternetDaysLeftAlarm

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
        // Do whatever you need
    }
}
```

Also, as some people already mentioned here, watch out for `@ActivityContext`. Instead, you should just use `@ApplicationContext`

Answer (score 1):

`@ActivityContext` can only use in Activity lifecycle but instead of this you can use `@ApplicationContext`.

```
class SomeClass @Inject contructor(@ApplicationContext private val ctx: Context){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes annotated with `@ActivityContext` can only be injected inside objects that are `@ActivityScoped`. So yes you are right, the `context` is the problem here.